# Qt: cursor blinking cause repaint of parent widget?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtwidgets

Bellow you can see minimal example code to demonstrate problem.
If you run it and give focus to `QLineEdit`, you get output every second: `paintEvent`, `paintEvent` and so on.
I can not understand why `MyW::paintEvent` called on every
cursor blinking in child widget? As you see I do not configure `QLineEdit`,
by default on my linux box it have no transparent elements,
but still for some reason cursor cause all widgets to redraw their content?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QLineEdit>

class MyW final : public QWidget {
public:
    MyW() {
        //setAutoFillBackground(false);
    }
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e) {       
        e->accept();
        qDebug("paintEvent");
        QPainter painter{this};
        painter.fillRect(rect(), Qt::green);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MyW w;
    w.resize(600, 600);
    w.show();
    auto le = new QLineEdit{&w};
    le->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: many times they are repainted as they expect to interact with the mouse, for example they are processing the hover event, and so other types of events, is a normal behavior.

Comment: I think this is standard behavior by `paintEvent`. It'd make no sense for a `paintEvent` not to be issued whenever the widget needs to be painted. May be you can use `update()` to handle widget updates.  Have a look at [how-can-i-make-paintevent-triggered-only-when-update-is-called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777535/how-can-i-make-paintevent-triggered-only-when-update-is-called).

Comment: @SumitJha `not to be issued whenever the widget needs to be painted` but what the to redraw `MyW` if cursor blink in widgets on top of it, this is very simple optmization, and this is question why Qt not do such kind of optimization.

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes mouse moving is also amazing reason to redraw. I read that since Qt 5 it uses double buffering by default, why not just take pixmap from buffer cache, why issue qpaintevent instead.